# Regex Help Needed for data in multiple formats

Tags: regex, vb.net

I have the below list of variations on some data and I have been trying to figure a regex to be able to break all of them up in to two groups. Group A should be **UM** and Group B should be **832** or **832.0** if the decimal and any number should follow. For example if it were UM832.56.N I would only want to get the **832.56** for Group B. Group A will always be letters and should always start the string, but as you can see there is one where they are at the end. If I can come up with something to fit all but that one, I would be happy to throw an error for that one.

1. UM 832.0.N
2. UM 832.0
3. UM 832.N
4. UM 832
5. UM832
6. 832UM
7. UM832.0.N
8. UM832.0
9. UM832.N

I have come up with the below Regex that seams to partially work.

```
(?<GroupA>^[a-zA-Z]*)|(?<GroupB>\d*[\.]*\d*)
```

The output I get from this is:

```
Original Data: UM 832.0.N     Match: UM
Original Data: UM 832.0.N     Match: 
Original Data: UM 832.0.N     Match: 832.0
Original Data: UM 832.0.N     Match: .
Original Data: UM 832.0.N     Match: 
Original Data: UM 832.0.N     Match: 
Original Data: UM 832.0.N     Match: 
Original Data: UM 832.0.N     Match:
```

The code I am using is pretty simple vb.net:

```
Private Sub DebugParse(Data As String)
    Dim strRegex As String = "(?<GroupA>^[a-zA-Z]*)|(?<GroupB>\d*[\.]*\d*)"
    Dim myRegexOptions As RegexOptions = RegexOptions.IgnoreCase Or RegexOptions.Multiline Or RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace
    Dim myRegex As New Regex(strRegex, myRegexOptions)
    Dim strTargetString As String = "UM 832.0.N" 

    For Each myMatch As Match In myRegex.Matches(strTargetString)
        If myMatch.Success Then
            Debug.WriteLine("Original Data: " & Data & "     Match: " & myMatch.Value)
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

I am pretty sure this is something simple that I am overlooking, like a flag or a misunderstanding of regex, but I have hit a frustration barrier at this point.

**EDIT**
Ok so after re-reading my question here I realized that part of my frustration was the empty match. I am still not sure why they are there, but I can at least skip them in code. So what is allowing the period (aka decimal point) to be a match?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran your data using `(?<GroupA>^[a-zA-Z]+)\s*(?<GroupB>\d*\.*\d*).*$` and only `RegexOptions.Multiline` set, gave this output:

```
            GroupA  GroupB
UM 832.0.N  UM      832.0
UM 832.0    UM      832.0
UM 832.N    UM      832.
UM 832      UM      832
UM832       UM      832
UM832.0.N   UM      832.0
UM832.0     UM      832.0
UM832.N     UM      832.
```

As you can see, you data No. 6 (`832UM`) is not listed in the output because it failed the match.

Answer (score 0):

Would this do the trick??

```
(?<GroupA>UM)\s?(?<BroupB>[0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)?)
```